# Error when importing a folder that is under the same main folder. | Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to import something from a file in the folder I am working in:

For example:

```
from lib.db import db
```

This is supposed to import the file from a folder in the main folder I am working on. I get this error though:

```
  File "c:\Users\achut\Downloads\updated-discord.py-tutorial-master\updated-discord.py-tutorial-master\lib\bot\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from lib.db import db
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.db'
```

I also tried importing it like this:

```
from ..db import db
```

I was trying this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0luhkRM188Y and even went as far as to download the entire github repository code with the same error. It works for everyone else though. The github repo for this video is: https://github.com/Carberra/updated-discord.py-tutorial. Ignore the cogs and extra stuff in the repo. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found is:

```
from db import db
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, that it is not in your Python path, so you need to specify, that you are importing something relative to your current package.

```
from .lib.db import lib
```

Comment: I still get this error:
  File "c:\Users\achut\Desktop\EZUTILITYPIPENV PREFIX\lib\rblxbot.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .lib.db import lib
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: I am terribly sorry then, I'm not sure how to solve your problem. I'll give you an upvote to see if somebody else can help solve your issue. I wish you the best of luck in getting this fixed!

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, I have upvoted your answer too. :)